# Make a calculated field in mongo db

Tags: mongodb, calculated-field

I have two collections one is Employee and the other one is a salary. I want to make a calculated field in employee collection call monthly salary. How can I access a `SALARY` from Salary collection and divided by 12?

**Here are some info I included in MongoDB:**

```
db.Salary.insertMany([

  {
    "POSITION": "1",
    "BRANCH_SIZE": "HQ",
    "SALARY": "150000"
  },
  {
    "POSITION": "2",
    "BRANCH_SIZE": "HQ",
    "SALARY": "100000"
  },
  {
    "POSITION": "3",
    "BRANCH_SIZE": "HQ",
    "SALARY": "70000"
  },
  {
    "POSITION": "4",
    "BRANCH_SIZE": "HQ",
    "SALARY": "30000"
  },
  {
    "POSITION": "5",
    "BRANCH_SIZE": "HQ",
    "SALARY": "56000"
  }
])

db.Employee.insertMany([

  {
    "EMPLOYEE_NO": "1000",
    "LNAME": "Wyatt",
    "FNAME": " Stefan"
    "CITY": "MANKATO",
    "STATE": "MN",
    "ZIP": "56001",
    "STATUS": "1",
    "POSITION": "1"
  },
  {
    "EMPLOYEE_NO": "1029",
    "LNAME": "Martin",
    "FNAME": "Edward",
    "STATUS": "1",
    "START_DATE": "02-MAY-95",
    "END_DATE": "",
    "BRANCH_NO": "103",
    "BRANCH_SIZE": "MD",
    "POSITION": "3"
  },
  {
    "EMPLOYEE_NO": "1089",
    "LNAME": "Stewart",
    "FNAME": "Macy",
    "CITY": "SAINT PAUL",
    "BRANCH_NO": "101",
    "BRANCH_SIZE": "BG",
    "POSITION": "4"
  }
])
```

I want to make a monthly salary for each employee. How can I do that?
Thanks in advance.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/materialized-views/.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$lookup` and `$divide` operator to grab salary from salary collection, and divide one of the fields by 12.

**Example:**

```js
db.employee.aggregate([{
    $lookup: {
      from: 'salary',
      localField: 'POSITION',
      foreignField: 'POSITION',
      as: 'salary',
    },
  },
  {
    {
      $project: {
        dividedSalary: {
          $divide: ["$salary.SALARY", 12]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Hi got this error:-- 2020-06-24T17:50:22.457-0500 E  QUERY    [js] SyntaxError: expected property name, got '{' :
@(shell):10:4

Comment: Have you replaced all of the queries above with the original data that you have? for example such as collection names and field names.

Comment: Yes and I do have salary field in float foarmat.  db.Employee.aggregate([{
    $lookup: {
      from: 'Salary',
      localField: "POSITION",
      foreignField: "POSITION",
      as: 'MonthlySalary',
    },
  },
  {
    {
      $project: {
        dividedSalary: {
          $divide: ["$Salary.SALARY", 12]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])

Comment: You must change in the `$divide: ["$Salary.SALARY", 12]` section to `$divide: ["$MonthlySalary.SALARY", 12]`